# Group by and select columns not included in the aggregate

Tags: sql, aggregates

Given I have columns A B C D …..  Z

I want to  Group-By on A, B , C Having Count(*) > 1 and then for each of those rows, I want to SELECT the rest of the Columns as well that were not included in the  aggregate.

The result would be like

```
Occurrences    A   B   C    D   E   F    G  ------- Z
3              e   e   k    q   r   y    e  ------- j
3              e   e   k    f   t   d    t  ------- y
3              e   e   k    w   e   q    c  ------- d
2              f   r   s    w   e   q    c  ------- d
2              f   r   s    w   e   q    c  ------- d
```

How can I do that?

Comment: The general GROUP BY rule says:
If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function.

Comment: You should include your rdbms tag for sql question. Some functions arent available on all databases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want `GROUP BY`, you want `ORDER BY`.  To get the first column, you can use window functions, which are ANSI standard and supported by most databases:

```
select t.*
from (select count(*) over (partition by a, b, c) as occurrences,
             t.*
      from t
      order by a, b, c
     ) t
where occurrences > 1;
```

Comment: Would you expect `select max(some numeric column name) over (partition by a, b, c) . . . ` to also work, i.e. is max() function considered a window function?  
  
If so is there a specific version of mysql you require to use `over (partition by . . . )` syntax?