# how to include column data that you do not want used in distinct group by set calculation

Tags: mysql, group-by, distinct

I've been unable to find search hit explaining how to include column data that i do not want used as part of sql distinct group by set calculation

I have a select statement returning just the records I want, i.e. the latest support request by a specific company we collaborate with . . .

`SELECT company, max(created_date) FROM support_request WHERE critical_vendor = 1 and status <> 'Cancelled' GROUP BY company ;`

. . . and now i just want to include the contact data associated with that distinct group by set calculation without it affecting that set selection but adding it is, as i would intuitively expect to be able to do so, it appears is going to end up affecting the distinct group by set calculation as i get noted syntax error which is asking me to include it in the group by clause

`SELECT company, max(created_date), contact_name FROM support_request WHERE critical_vendor = 1 and status <> 'Cancelled' GROUP BY company ;`

`Expression #3 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'isrm_request.qc_contact' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by`

Answer (score 1):

You use the partition over clause

```
SELECT  company,
 max(created_date) OVER (partition by company)  as max_created_date, contact_name
     FROM support_request
    WHERE critical_vendor = 1 and status <> 'Cancelled'
     GROUP BY company
```

Comment: Thanks. That's a whole lot cleaner than the inner join on group by i've been experimenting with. I'm getting a `check the manual . . . for the right syntax to use near '(partition by company) as max_created_date, request_id FROM isrm_request ' at line 1`  issue with the following use of it where i don't readily see where i've gone wrong.
```SELECT company, max(created_date) OVER (partition by company) as max_created_date, request_id FROM support_request WHERE critical_vendor = 1 and status <> 'Cancelled' and created_date < date_sub(curdate(), interval 1 year) GROUP BY company ; ```

Comment: Looking at [MySql | Partition By Clause](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mysql-partition-by-clause/#:~:text=MySQL%20%7C%20PARTITION%20BY%20Clause%201%20It%20is,whole%20table%20is%20considered%20as%20a%20single%20partition.) it says `This clause works on windows functions only. Like- RANK(), LEAD(), LAG() etc.`.

It would seem the max() aggregation function not being a window function cannot be used with over( partition by) syntax.

Comment: Looking at this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33305624/group-by-and-select-columns-not-included-in-the-aggregate if its suggesting that count(*) is a window function then i would think max(column name) is also a window [ / aggregation ??? ] function that can be used with `over (partition by . . . )` syntax and perhaps issue is with version 5.7.34-37 of mysql i'm using.

Comment: Looking at this post https://learnsql.com/blog/over-clause-mysql/ outlines the windowing that over(partition by) provides and that appears to be for computing dimensionalized facts and not selecting top or max or min records like we were trying to accomplish.